# ORA-04091 (mutating table) only if specific field is filled

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

Got a table, which has a key on itself:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
+ ID + ID_PARENT + IS_PARENT +
+----+-----------+-----------+
+  1 +    (null) +         0 +
+  2 +    (null) +         1 +
+  3 +         2 +         0 +
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

As you see, ID `1` is on its own, `3` is a child of `2`.

Now I want to have a trigger, that on INSERT/UPDATE ...

- errors, if an inserted row is it's own parent (not possible)
- if it has an `ID_PARENT`, set the parent's `IS_PARENT` to `1`

This is my approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_table_set_parent
    BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON table
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.id_parent IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
    IF :new.id = :new.id_parent
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20666, 'A gap cant be the parent of itself. More information here: https://youtu.be/hqRZFWE1X_A');
    END IF;
    UPDATE table
    SET is_parent = 1
    WHERE id = :new.id_parent;
END;
/
```

The error works as intended, woohoo! But now when inserting, I have problems.

When inserting a row *without* `ID_PARENT`, it works (because trigger won't trigger at all).

Inserting a row, whose parent's `ID_PARENT = (null)`:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, ID_PARENT) VALUES (4, 1);
```

-> Works!

But inserting a row, whose parent got an `ID_PARENT`:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, ID_PARENT) VALUES (5, 3);
```

-> Errors:

```
ORA-04091: Tabelle TABLE wird gerade geändert, Trigger/Funktion sieht dies möglicherweise nicht
ORA-06512: in "TRI_TABLE_SET_PARENT", Zeile 6
ORA-04088: Fehler bei der Ausführung von Trigger "TRI_TABLE_SET_PARENT"
ORA-06512: in "TRI_TABLE_SET_PARENT", Zeile 6
ORA-04088: Fehler bei der Ausführung von Trigger "TRI_TABLE_SET_PARENT"
```

Updating the table doesn't work at all, same error.

Ok, so I understand that I can't select stuff that *might* be changed simultaniously. But I'm updating, and also I'm checking that I don't reference the same rows.

So what am I missing?

Comment: To cirtumvent these kind of problems always have a look at compound triggers!

Answer (score 2):

The **evil thing** in relational database is **redundancy** which you try to introduce.

More *correct* relational approach would be to define the table without the `IS_PARENT` column.

```
select * from my_parent order by id;
        ID  ID_PARENT
---------- ----------
         1           
         2           
         3          2
```

... and add the redundant column in an *access view*

```
create view V_MY_PARENT  as
select a.ID, a.ID_PARENT,
case when exists (select null from my_parent where ID_PARENT = a.ID) then 1 else 0 end as IS_PARENT
from my_parent a
order by a.ID;
```

To get all *non parents* you access the view

```
select * from V_MY_PARENT
where is_parent = 0;

        ID  ID_PARENT  IS_PARENT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1                     0
         3          2          0
```

If you want to *materialize the redundancy* (e.g. for performance reasons) use `MATERIALIZED VIEW`s.

With this approach you will **not end** with **parents classified as no parents** or vice versa, which is quite possible in your design.

Comment: As your approach is basically the thing todo, your select isn't correct: You have to make sure that you only get one record for any ID_PARENT in your left join or use `case when exists (...)` instead.

Comment: @Radagast81 you are right, unfortunately there is no *semi* join in SQL;)

Comment: Info: for now I simply do `WHERE b.is IS NULL` as this is a simple boolean. But how would I do this if I only know the coloumn's content after the CASE clause's operation?

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace

```
UPDATE "table"
   SET id_parent = 1
 WHERE id = :new.id_parent;
```

with

```
if :old.id = :new.id_parent and updating then
   :new.id_parent := 1;
end if;
```

e.g avoid using a DML within the same "table" against `ORA-04091`.

P.S. being `table` as a reserved keyword, I replaced with `"table"`.

Comment: wait, maybe I misunderstand this, but I dont want to update the NEW insertion. I insert a NEW set, which has id_parent. And this id_parent points to an OLD record, of which I want to set is_parent to 1. (it's an unfortunate naming, there is IS_parent and ID_parent)

Comment: @Trollwut then you seem to need ":old.id = :new.id_parent and updating" for if statement.

Comment: yes, but then I guess it won't work for the INSERT triggering anymore

Answer (score 1):

The error cause is that you are updating row that you didn't inserted yet.

you could update the data you are inserting using `:new` keyword.

so the solution will be replacing the update statement with

```
:new.is_parent := 1
```

Answer (score 1):

ORA-04091 (table is mutating, trigger may not see it) occurs here because you have a BEFORE trigger defined on "TABLE", and in the body of the trigger you're attempting to update "TABLE". Oracle doesn't allow this as it can lead to a trigger loop (i.e. if this was allowed your program could execute a statement which causes the trigger to fire; within the body of the trigger a statement executes which causes the trigger to fire; within the body of the trigger a statement executes which causes the trigger to fire; within the body of the trigger a statement executes which causes the trigger to fire; within the body of the trigger a statement executes which causes the trigger to fire; etc). So you're not allowed to do this in a BEFORE trigger. The simplest fix is to change the trigger to an AFTER trigger. In other words, change `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table` to `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table`. In this particular case it doesn't appear this would be a problem, but I don't know what constraints you have on your table which might make this unacceptable. Give it a try.